# QTableView::edit( const QModelIndex &index ) failed

Tags: qt, qtableview, qabstracttablemodel

I am trying to prevent user from entering the same data into my model, which is subclassed from **QAbstractTableModel**.

```
bool MyModel::setData( const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role )
{
    bool result = false;
    ...
    // Test if my model already has the same data
    result = findItem( value.toString() ) != -1;
    ...
    if ( result )
        emit( dataChanged( index, index );
    else
        emit ( dataInvalid( index ) );

    return result;
}
```

Now I should catch the signal and turn my table view (which type is **QTableView**) back to editing state:

```
void MyWindow::dataInvalid( const QModelIndex &index )
{
    myTableView->edit( index );
}
```

But when I run my application I got message in the console and **QTableView** does not turn to editing state:

```
edit: edit failed
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I think it fails, because when you call edit() on your view, it is still in the edit mode and setData() function is not exited yet.

Comment: Thank you very much, @vahancho!
I added `Qt::QueuedConnection` when connecting to `dataInvalid` signal and it works!
The problem was because `QTableView` was **still** in `QAbstractItemView::EditState` when I called `QTableView::edit( const QModelIndex &index )`.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When calling

```
myTableView->edit( index )
```

my view ***is still*** in **QAbstractItemView::EditState** and that is the reason of failure.
Solution is to add **Qt::QueuedConnection** when connecting to signal:

```
MyWindow::MyWindow()
{
    ...
    connect( myModel, SIGNAL( dataInvalid( QModelIndex ) ),
        this, SLOT( dataInvalid( QModelIndex ) ), Qt::QueuedConnection );
    ...
}
```

Now everything works fine.